# C - Makefile possibly missing a line

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, separator

I'll say first I don't have as much experience which makefiles as I wished, this is actually my first. 
The error I currently get is:

**Makefile:1:  missing separator.  Stop.**

This happens when I try to run the make command.

As far as I know this means that I'm missing a hard tab at the first line it tries to run, I think at least.

I'm not missing a hard tab though as far as I know, so I'm assuming I'm just missing a whole line somewhere.

```
CFLAGS = -ansi -Wall -pedantic
HEADERS = menu.h file1.h file2.h file3.h file4.h
OBJECTS = menu.o file1.o file2.o file3.o file4.o
CC = gcc

all:runprog

runprog:$(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o runprog

menu.o:menu.c $(HEADERS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS)

file1.o:file1.c $(HEADERS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS)

file2.o:file2.c $(HEADERS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS)

file3.o:file3.c $(HEADERS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS)

file4.o:file4.c $(HEADERS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS)

clean:rm -f *.o runprog
```

Comment: There must be more to your makefile than that.  The error message lists the problem at line 1 (`Makefile:1`) but `CFLAGS = -ansi -Wall -pedantic` is fine; no error here.  I do note that your last line is wrong (you're missing a newline/TAB after the `clean:`.  I also note that your compilation lines are completely wrong... you don't list the source etc.  But none of that is related to your error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clean target has its code in the place of dependencies. Also, your code uses spaces instead of tabs. Additionally, you forgot to add the `.c` files to the CC command lines. Moreover, you can simplify all the rules to

```
CFLAGS = -ansi -Wall -pedantic
HEADERS = menu.h file1.h file2.h file3.h file4.h
OBJECTS = menu.o file1.o file2.o file3.o file4.o
CC = gcc

all:runprog

runprog:$(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o runprog

%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f *.o runprog
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to help me out, that works perfectly! Extremely neat too, I did feel I must be doing something wrong having to write all those lines for each specific file.

I'll have to research a bit so I can get a full understanding of the "$@ $<" calls, and also "%.o: %.c".